# Java Securely Handle Password Variable

Tags: java, security, memory, hash, passwords

I'm not the most experienced programmer especially when it comes to desktop applications.

Just an experiment that I am working on is taking a password, hashing it with MD5, then displaying the hash. No problem there.

Now, I know virtually nothing about data structures and how things are stored on the stack. But the aim is for this program to securely handle the password and the MD5 hash so it doesn't leak out into memory and could be potentially recovered.

I've read a number of posts about this, but they all are more concerned with actually storing the password in memory to be retrievable.

Here is the relevant code:

```
String pass = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
pass = Hashing.md5().hashString(pass, Charsets.UTF_8).toString();
hashField.setText(pass);
```

And to put it into perspective, link to a screenshot of whats going on:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nknHj.jpg

As far as I know, I'm retrieving the input from the password field correctly, but I've read storing them as strings is a no-no.

Then I need to display the MD5 sum securely.
Then upon exit, overwrite the data?

Comment: As per my knowledge no body can sniff data from JVM.. It has good sand box feature..

Comment: Sounds like that solves it the. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Protecting the password in memory from who?

Comment: In a real life scenario, you should not use a single round of MD5 for password hashing. Use bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDF2.